# How to use regular expressions with \w\d inside ()

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, replace

I created an example of text:

```
dog cat worm
```

And I want to replace everything but not the first word and without knowing what's there.

At first I tried this:`:%s/\(dog\)\(.*\)/\1/g`

This works fine but when I change it to: `:%s/\(\w\)\(.*\)/\1/g`

it returns

```
d
```

For second word regexp `:%s/.*\(cat\)\(.*\)/\1/g` I get `cat` so it's just as I wanted but with `:%s/\w\(\w\)\(.*\)/\1/g` I get `c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` does not represent a word but merely a word-character.

You want `:%s/\(\w\+\)\(.*\)/\1/g`

Also, in this simple example the `/g` does nothing though

Comment: Ok it works for the first example but second one: `:%s/\(\w\+\)\(\w\+\)\(.*\)/\2/` returns `g` from `dog` word. Anyway is there a way of not escaping all characters like +)(? Regex gets messy really quick because of this.

Comment: Ok I figured it out: `:%s/\(\w\+\)\s\(\w\+\)\(.*\)/\2/` The problem was with space character. As my regexp cover full line I needed to add space character as it separates words. Thanks for help!

Comment: @A.Dziedziczak If you don't want to have to escape so many characters, use a "very magic" pattern. See `:help /\v`